# web3.js how can i save value in variable from function?

Tags: web3js

I am trying to get started with web3.js. There are two different examples for getBlockNumber or getBalance:

```
web3.eth.getBlockNumber(function (error, result) {
      console.log(result);
});
```

or shorter

```
web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
.then(console.log);
```

But how do I save the output to process it further? No matter how I try, I only get "Promise {  }".
I have read many posts on this but have not found a solution that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
let result;    
const blockNumber = async () => {
        result = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
};
blockNumber();
```

Let me know if that solve your problem. Actually "everything" it's a promise in web3 that's why you need async/await

^ console.log the result variable ofc.

Comment: Thank you. Wenn ich das so verwende und blockNumber() in console.log ausgebe erhalte ich nach wie vor Promise und keine Variable. I try to rewrite this code that it works (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3478): I need a list with all transactions from an address